# Meaning of doc-available()

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have found this scenario(below) on one of the XSLT files that has been done already. However, I could not find the meaning of it. Could anyone please let me know the meaning of the below code?

```
<xsl:variable name="paramsDoc" select="if (doc-available('input:request')) then doc('input:request') else ()"/>
```

What this line `doc-available('input:request')` exactly does? How it works?

Comment: You didn't find it when you looked it up in the spec? http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available

Answer (score 1):

The `doc-available($URI)` function checks whether the instruction `doc($URI` would actually be successful, i.e. if the document exists or not.

It is useful to know beforehand if a document can be retrieved and only process it if it's available. In your case, the line

```
<xsl:variable name="paramsDoc" select="if (doc-available('input:request')) then doc('input:request') else ()"/>
```

means:

> Create a variable (a node-set) with the name "paramsDoc". If the URI "input-request" can be used to locate and read a document, then retrieve the document and return its document node , otherwise store "()" as the value of that variable.

However, in my opinion, "input:request" does not seem to be a file name, nor is it a variable.

You should also bear in mind that if `doc-available` returns false, it does not always mean that a file is inexistent. There might be other reasons as to why it cannot be read or parsed.

**EDIT**: As suggested by @DanielHaley, in case `doc-available()` is not successful, an *empty sequence* is returned, `()`.

Comment: It would also be good to note that `()` is an empty sequence.

Comment: @DanielHaley You're right - that's a sensible addition. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The `doc` and `doc-available` functions are part of XPath and XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 does not have "result tree fragment"s at all so the explanation mentioning "result tree fragment" is wrong.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Thanks for spotting this. It should actually read "node-set". Apologies for the inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

The `doc` function will raise an error if you pass it a URI that cannot be loaded.  The `doc-available` is a way to test a particular URI before trying to retrieve it.

The fragment you've given will set the `paramsDoc` variable to the document root node of the XML document loaded from the URI "input:request" (which I'm guessing must be a special URI scheme that you're processor uses to supply input from some external source), but if that document is not available then the variable will be set to an empty sequence rather than causing an error.